# Creating new columns by iterationg over rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a pandas data frame like this:

```
    dx1      dx2    dx3    dx4    dx5       dx6     dx7
0   25041   40391   5856    0     V4511    V5867    30000
1   25041   40391   25081   5856  5363     3572     0
2   25041   40391   42822   0     5856     0        0
3   25061   40391   0       0     0        0        0
4   25041   40391   0       5856  25081    V4511    25051
```

I want to create additional column(s) for cell values like 25041,40391,5856 etc. So there will be a column 25041 with value as 1 or 0 if 25041 occurs in that particular row in any dxs columns. I am using this code and it works.

```
X11['25041'] = X11.isin(['25041']).any(1).astype(int)
```

But there are many values within the cells and for each of them I want to create similar columns. For that I want to use a for LOOP. I did the following:

1) Created a numpy matrix from data frame

```
mat = X11.as_matrix(columns=None)
```

2) Counted the unique occurrences of cell values

```
values, counts = np.unique(mat.astype(str), return_counts=True)
```

3) But when I tried to run this code, it does not spit out correct columns as expected:

```
for x in np.nditer(values):
    print (x)
    X11['x'] = X11.isin(['x']).any(1).astype(int)
```

print(x) prints all unique cell values. But only one new column, x, gets appended with 0 values in X11 data frame.

Whereas when I am doing manually one-by-one for each cell value like this then I am getting new columns added to data frame.

```
X11['5856'] = X11.isin(['5856']).any(1).astype(int)
```

I have hundreds of cell values therefore I can not do it manually. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the x in the for loop as a string and not the variable.

```
for x in values:
    print (x)
    X11[x] = X11.isin([x]).any(1).astype(int)
```

That should do ya.

Comment: :I tried that one but it gives error--

TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

Comment: I did not figure out the edit. It appears same. I am still getting the same error. TypeError  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-295-f24ff8d6f716> in <module>()
      1 for x in np.nditer(values):
      2     print(x)
----> 3     X11[x] = X11.isin([x]).any(1).astype(int)

TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

Comment: Change 'np.nditer(values)' to just values, or copy and paste.

Comment: Above method is taking forever when I many thousands rows. Is there another way to execute the same logic which will take care many thousands rows?

Comment: How many total unique values do you have in these rows that will result in new columns? I only ask, because if you have thousands of rows with thousands of unique values, you're going to end up with an exponential amount of columns and it'll become unwieldy rather quickly regardless of the technique for creating the new columns.